# How to use a static mutable reference in a loop with async move?

Tags: rust

I have code with a mutable reference with the `'static` lifetime and I am trying to use it in the loop which has `async move`:

```rust
fn baz(_s: &mut String) {
    // do something
}

fn main() {
    let bar: &'static mut String = Box::leak(Box::new("test".to_string()));
    loop {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            baz(bar);
        });

        // some conditions here to exit from the loop
    }
}
```

The Rust compiler suggests reborrowing, but it is syntactically incorrect, the first time I've stumbled on that:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `bar`
  --> src/main.rs:8:33
   |
6  |       let bar: &'static mut String = Box::leak(Box::new("test".to_string()));
   |           --- move occurs because `bar` has type `&mut String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
7  |       loop {
8  |           tokio::spawn(async move {
   |  _________________________________^
9  | |             baz(bar);
   | |                 --- use occurs due to use in generator
10 | |         });
   | |_________^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
   |
help: consider creating a fresh reborrow of `bar` here
   |
8  |         tokio::spawn(async move &mut *{
   |                                 ++++++
```

How I can use this mutable reference in such a loop? I'm fighting against borrowing in the loop and `async move` wanting to do a copy/clone.

Comment: even if you leak it, you can only have a `&mut` at a time, so this is never gonna work. You should use some kind of synchronization, probably a `Mutex`

Comment: Fill a bug for the invalid suggestion, please.

Comment: @Netwave Thank you. You are absolutelly right. Haven't thought about it. CAn you please post the answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Done https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/96908

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have a (**one**) `&mut` at a time, so in order to use it as a shared resource you have to use some kind of synchronization. A [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) may come in handy here.